# Determine whether the fourier series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

I have calculated the Fourier Series of $g\left(x\right)=x$ on $\left(-\pi,\pi\right]$ extended periodically to $\mathbb{R}$ to be
$$g\left(x\right)=2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n}\sin\left(nx\right)$$

I now need to determine and explain whether the Fourier series converges at $x=\pi$ but I'm not sure how.

If it involves finding the left/right limits/derivatives, I'm not sure how to find these for a Fourier Series.

Comment: What is $\sin(n\pi)$?

Answer (score 3):

for $x=\pi$, the series is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sin(n\pi)
=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 0
=
0
$$

so the series converges to 0 at $\pi$. We expect this because 0 is the midpoint between $g(-\pi)$ and $g(\pi)$